# Does WSO2 IS support 2 key pairs for resident SAML identity provider - one for encryption and other one for signing?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We have to federate our WSO2 Identity Server with external (government) SAML IDP. Their new requirement from 2021 is to separate encryption keys from signing keys. Does WSO2 IS support it? Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure separate keystores with one for data encryption and other for message signing like SAML. Please find more details from [1].

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/administer/configuring-keystores-in-wso2-products/